# Getting Field 'None' expected a number but got 'update'. when using UpdateView in Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am using UpdateView for my update page, but I get this error:
Field 'None' expected a number but got 'update'.

my urls.py looks like this:

```
path('post/<pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_update'),
```

Everything works fine if I change my update URL to anything other than "post". For example, this works fine:

```
path('abcxyz/<pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_update'),
```

I would like to use the word "post" in URL, because i also use it in the other URLs and they work just fine (except for delete view, which gives me the same error). Is there any way to fix this error without changing the URL?

Note: It has worked before, but it broke at some point when I was trying to use django-PWA. I'm not sure if this is related though.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Share the full list of URLs. Likely you have overlapping URL patterns where it takes `<pk>` as update.

Comment: Thank you @WillemVanOnsem ! you're right, i have this pattern above the update pattern that causes the problem:
    path('post/<year>/<month>/', FilteredPostListView.as_view(), name='filtered_post'),

changing the order solved it.

Comment: you can use `path('post/<int:year>/<int:month>/', FilteredPostListView.as_view(), name='filtered_post'),` such that it will only trigger the path if `year` and `month` are sequences of digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because you have another path like:

```
path('post/update/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_update'),
```

or something similar. It is possible that one or both `update/`s are URL parameters.

If you then for example visit `post/update/update`, and your `PostUpdateView` is defined first, the it will trigger the view with `pk='update'`.

If the primary key is simply a number, you can make use of the `<int:…>` path converter to prevent triggering the view when `pk` is something else than a sequence of digits:

```
path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_update'),
```

**EDIT**: Based on your comment, there was another view before this one with:

```
path('post/<year>/<month>/', FilteredPostListView.as_view(), name='filtered_post')
```

If one thus visits `post/123/update`, it will trigger the `FilteredPostListView` with `123` as `year`, and `update` as month, and hence it will raise an error.

You can put the path *below* that of the `ProductUpdateListView`, and you furthermore might want to use the `<int:…>` as well to only trigger the view when both parameters are sequences of digits:

```
path('post/<int:year>/<int:month>/', FilteredPostListView.as_view(), name='filtered_post')
```